# How can i save a list/matrix in binary format in KDB?

Tags: python, list, numpy, save, kdb

I am trying to [`save`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/save/) a [matrix](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/3_Lists/#3112-formal-definition-of-matrices) to file in binary format in KDB as per below:

```
matrix: (til 10)*/:til 10;
save matrix;
```

However, I get the error `'type`.

I guess `save` only works with tables? In which case does anyone know of a workaround?

Finally, I would like to read the matrix from the binary file into Python with [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html), which I presume is just:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.fromfile('C:/q/w32/matrix', dtype='f')
```

Is that right?

*Note: I'm aware of [KDB-Python libraries](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api), but have been unable to install them thus far.*

Answer (score 2):

`save` does work, you just have to reference it by name.

```
save`matrix
```

You can also save using

```
`:matrix set matrix;
`:matrix 1: matrix;
```

But I don't think you'll be able to read this into python directly using numpy as it is stored in kdb format. It could be read into python using one of the python-kdb interfaces (e.g PyQ) or by storing it in a common format such as csv.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to save in KDB+ IPC format and then read it into Python with [qPython](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython) as a Pandas DataFrame. 
On the KDB+ side you can save it with

```
matrix:(til 10)*/:til 10;
`:matrix.ipc 1: -8!matrix;
```

On the Python side you do

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from qpython.qreader import QReader

with open('matrix.ipc',"rb") as f:
    matrix = DataFrame(QReader(f).read().data)

print(matrix)
```